# Differentiability and subsequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Let $ f $ be a function such that $ f' $ exists and continious at $ x=0 $.

It is given that exists a sequence $ x_{n} $ such that $ f\left(x_{n}\right)\cdot f\left(x_{n+1}\right)<0 $ for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, and $ 0<x_{n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $.

Prove that $ f\left(0\right)=f'\left(0\right) $.

Now, I have a proof but I didnt use the fact that $ f' $ is continious at $ x=0 $ and it concerns me.

Here's the proof:

From the given details we can build 2 subsequences  $ x_{n_{k},}x_{n_{j}} $ such that $ f\left(x_{n_{K}}\right)>0 $ for each natural $ k $, and $ f\left(x_{n_{j}}\right)<0 $ for all natural $ j $.

Since $ x_{n_k} $ and $ x_{n_j} $ are subsequences of $ x_n $ it follows that $ \lim_{j\to\infty}x_{n_{j}}=0 $ and $ \lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_{k}}=0 $ .

Now since $ f $ is continious at 0, it follows that

$ \lim_{x\to0}f\left(x\right)=0 $ and by Heine's definition for limit, it follows that for each sequnce $ a_n $ such that $ 0<a_{n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(a_{n}\right)=f\left(0\right) $.

Thus:

$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(f\left(x_{n_{K}}\right)\right)=f\left(0\right)$

and $ \lim_{j\to\infty}\left(f\left(x_{n_{j}}\right)\right)=f\left(0\right) $.

But since $ f(x_{n_k}) > 0 $ for each $ k $, it follows that  $ f\left(0\right)\geq0 $. and since $ f(x_{n_j}) < 0 $ for each $ j $, it follows that $ f(0)\leq 0 $. All in all we get that $ f(0)=0 $.

Now in the same way, because $ f' $ **exists** at $ 0 $, it follows that

$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x-0}=f'\left(0\right) $ we proved that $ f(0)=0 $, thus

$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}=f'\left(0\right) $

And again by Heine's definition of the limit:

$\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac{f\left(x_{n_{j}}\right)}{x_{n_{j}}}=f'\left(0\right) $ thus $ f'(0)\leq 0 $, because for each $ j $ it follows that $ f(x_{n_j})<0 $ and $x_{n_j} >0 $.

and $ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f\left(x_{n_{k}}\right)}{x_{n_{k}}}=f'\left(0\right) $ thus $ f'(0)\geq 0 $ since $x_{n_k}>0 $ and $ f(x_{n_k}) >0 $.

Thus we get that $ f'\left(0\right)=0 $.

But we didnt use the continiuity of $ f' $ at $ x=0 $.

Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the proof does not use the continuity of $f'$. Just for a precision, you can write the proof in a much easier (and shorter) way (but the idea is the same as yours) :

First, because $(x_n)$ tends to $0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$, then $f(x_n)$ tends to $f(0)$. Let $n$ tend to $+\infty$ in the inequality $f(x_n)f(x_{n+1}) < 0$ : you get
$$f(0)^2 \leq 0$$

So $f(0)=0$.

Now, because $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and $x_n$ tends to $0$, you have
$$f'(0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x_{n+1})}{x_{n+1}}$$

So $$f'(0)^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x_n)f(x_{n+1})}{x_n x_{n+1}} \leq 0$$

So you deduce $f'(0)=0$.